# How to set contact name in customer portal header

Tags: customer-portal, header-bar

I am using customer portal and in Portal header I want to show contact name. Is it possible, if yes what is the approach?

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard functionality to change the portal header according to the user or contact name. But you are able to implement a custom visual force page (hide header and sidebar) and built your custom portal page.

But this requires to implement for each page a custom visual force page.